# Convert TensorFlow sparse_tensor_dense_matmul to embedding_lookup_sparse format

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

The TensorFlow [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/sparse_tensor_dense_matmul) mentions that the SparseTensor format expected by `sparse_tensor_dense_matmul` is: `sp_a (indices, values)`:

```
[0, 1]: a
[1, 0]: b
[1, 4]: c
[2, 2]: d
```

SparseTensor format expected by `embedding_lookup_sparse`: `sp_ids sp_weights`

```
[0, 0]: 1                [0, 0]: a
[1, 0]: 0                [1, 0]: b
[1, 1]: 4                [1, 1]: c
[2, 0]: 2                [2, 0]: d
```

How can I convert `sp_a` to `sp_ids` and `sp_weights` the second in TensorFlow? If not possible, how can I do it in numpy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ignore whether there exists a function in the Tensorflow API for this convertion, but this is how I would convert `sp_a` to `sp_ids` and `sp_weights`:

```
import tensorflow as tf


indices = tf.constant([[0, 1],
                       [1, 0],
                       [1, 4],
                       [2, 2]], dtype=tf.int64)
values = tf.constant([1, 2, 3, 4])  # a, b, c, d
dense_shape = tf.constant([3, 5], dtype=tf.int64)
sp_a = tf.SparseTensor(indices=indices,
                       values=values,
                       dense_shape=dense_shape)

# transform sp_a into sp_ids and sp_weights
# Get sp_ids values
sp_ids_values = tf.slice(sp_a.indices,
                         begin=[0, 1],
                         size=[-1, 1])
sp_ids_values = tf.squeeze(sp_ids_values)

# Get the indices for sp_ids and sp_weights
d1 = tf.slice(sp_a.indices,
              begin=[0, 0],
              size=[-1, 1])
d2 = tf.expand_dims(scan_accum(tf.squeeze(d1)),
                    axis=1)
indices_ = tf.concat([d1, d2],
                     axis=1)

# Build sp_ids and sp_weights
sp_ids = tf.SparseTensor(indices=indices_,
                         values=sp_ids_values,
                         dense_shape=sp_a.dense_shape)
sp_weights = tf.SparseTensor(indices=indices_,
                             values=sp_a.values,
                             dense_shape=sp_a.dense_shape)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run(sp_ids))
    print(sess.run(sp_weights))
```

I define `scan_accum` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46213552/5140223).