# How to convert [0,0,0,1,2,2] to [0,1,2,0,0,1]?

Tags: tensorflow

Using standard TensorFlow operators, how can I convert a 1D tensor which has values in ascending order to a 1D tensor in which each value is the number of times the value at the same index in the input tensor has appeared when scanning from left to right?
An example is given in the question title.

Comment: I don't see how the description of the problem can produce the example. Take the first value in the output. The "the value at the same index in the input tensor" is 0 (the first value in the input tensor). 0 appears 2 or 3 times "in the input tensor when scanning from left to right", depending on where you begin your scan. So, the first value in the output tensor should be either 2 or 3, not 0... I can see how this example can be produced if you scan from RIGHT to LEFT instead. Is that what you want?

Comment: Did my answer solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using [tf.while_loop](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/while_loop). I suggest the following solution:

```
import tensorflow as tf


def scan_accum(a):
    def condition(a):
        def c(counts, acc, i):
            return tf.less(i, tf.gather(tf.shape(a), 0))
        return c

    def body(a):
        def b(counts, acc, i):
            current = tf.gather(a, i)
            ant = tf.gather(a, tf.add(i, -1))
            update = tf.scatter_nd(tf.reshape(i, shape=(1, 1)),
                                   tf.expand_dims(acc, axis=0),
                                   shape=tf.shape(counts))
            counts_ = tf.cond(
                pred=tf.equal(current, ant),
                true_fn=lambda: counts + update,
                false_fn=lambda: counts
            )
            acc_ = tf.cond(
                pred=tf.equal(current, ant),
                true_fn=lambda: tf.add(acc, 1),
                false_fn=lambda: tf.constant(1, dtype=counts.dtype)
            )
            i_ = tf.add(i, 1)
            return [counts_, acc_, i_]
        return b

    i = tf.constant(1)
    counts = tf.zeros_like(a)
    acc = tf.constant(1, dtype=counts.dtype)
    counts, _, _ = tf.while_loop(cond=condition(a),
                                 body=body(a),
                                 loop_vars=[counts, acc, i])
    return counts

a = tf.constant([0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 2])
with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run(scan_accum(a)))  # prints [0 1 2 0 0 1]
```